# What is the easiest way to change data in one of the Knockout viewmodels while running in the browser?

Tags: knockout.js

I am running (my own built) KnockOut.JS application.
What is the easiest way to CHANGE data in one of the viewmodels?

I do not have a global JS object I can change in the console, and I have multiple elements with their own binding.
I can of course create a button and a method on the viewmodel, but I want to play around with some values on the viewmodel to see the effect in the UI.

Preferably in Chrome.

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/knockout.js/5066/debugging-a-knockout-js-application/17874/checking-the-binding-context-of-a-dom-element#t=201708081036143347831 to see how you can retrieve a reference using `ko.dataFor`

Comment: This is a very nice find! However, I don't see the changes I make in the viewmodel reflected in the DOM?

Comment: Are the properties `observable`? Are you correctly setting them using `(newValue)` instead of `= newValue` ?

Comment: @user3297291: Good one! That did the trick! So even if it is a duplicate, can you add it as an answer?

Comment: Sure, I'll write up a quick answer so others don't have to scan the comments to find the solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When developing a knockout website/application you often want to play around with different values to see how your UI reacts.

When your own code is neatly contained and not accessible via `window`, it can be difficult to gain access to your viewmodels.

Of course, you can modify your code to expose certain properties in window (e.g.: `window.myObsProp = this.myObsProp`). However, this requires you to edit your code and can be quite annoying when working with lists of viewmodels.

Therefore, a quick alternative is to use knockout's `dataFor` and `contextFor` utility functions.<sup>1</sup>

Using `ko.dataFor` or `ko.contextFor` you can return the binding context for a specific part of the DOM. `ko.dataFor(element)` is a shorthand for `ko.contextFor(element).$data`.

To quickly gain access to an element, most browsers expose a `$0` global variable that contains the last inspected element. You can therefore retrieve your viewmodel using:

1. Right mouse button -> inspect element
2. In console: `var vm = ko.dataFor($0)`

To retrieve properties and edit them:

3. get: `vm.myObsProp()`
4. set: `vm.myObsProp("some new value")`

An example on knockout's [hello world example](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/helloWorld.html)

[image: A GIF that shows how to inspect an element and retrieve its binding context]

<sub>1. *This does require you to expose `ko` in the global scope (`window`).*</sub>

Comment: Note: I figured it was okay to re-post my documentation article as an answer to this question, since documentation will be ["sun set"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation) in the near future and we can no longer link to it. Let me know if this is considered bad practice...

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would apply the bindings in a manner similar to this:

```
 ko.applyBindings(new Model());
```

But then the reference to the model is not available to you later on. Instead, if you keep a copy of the reference variable generated by `new Model()` you can change the observables within it, or check their values for debugging. Here's the pattern I employ when I need my model accessible to external code.

```
var vm = new Model();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Now, if you wanted you could check the values in `vm` or update the observables if you wish. See the example below.

```js
var Model= function() {
  var self = this;
  
  self.test = ko.observable("Initial Value");
}

var vm = new Model();
ko.applyBindings(vm);

setInterval(function() {
  vm.test("Value updated from external code!");
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    vm.test("New Value from external code!");
  }, 1000)
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-bind="textInput: test" />
<br/>
<span data-bind="text: test"></span>
```

Note: This might not be fully safe given that your `vm` is accessible under `window` object. So you might want to change it before deploying on production.