# How can I access an observable outside the ViewModel in KnockoutJS?

Tags: javascript, html, mvvm, knockout.js, observable

I'm using `KnockoutJS` to `data-bind` some elements in my `View`:

```
<div>
  <h2 data-bind="text: wTitle"></h1>
  <div data-bind="text: wSynopsis"></div>
</div>
```

In my `ViewModel`, I have `observables` that controls these elements. They change the elements' contents based on an `AJAX` call to Wikipedia.

Below is my `ViewModel` (I removed any non-relevant code):

```
var ViewModel = function() {
  self = this;

  this.wTitle = ko.observable('');
  this.wSynopsis = ko.observable('');

  this.wikiInfo = function(i) {
    var wikiURL = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=' + i + '&format=json&callback=wikiCallback';

    $.ajax({
      url: wikiURL,
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(response) {
        return new parseAjax(response);
      }
    })
    .fail(function() {
      return "Error: Cannot load Wikipedia data!";
    });
  }

  this.wikiInfo(Model.currentMarker);

  var parseAjax = function(response) {
    self.wTitle(response[0]);
    self.wSynopsis(response[2]);
  };

}
```

My `Model` is below (removed any non-relevant code for simplicity):

```
var Model = {
  currentMarker: 0
};
```

Now, I want to access that `observables` and change their value from outside my `ViewModel` (i.e. my `init()`, which is outside the `ViewModel`).

```
var init = function() {
  Model.currentMarker = marker;
  ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
}
```

An approach, is to change the `Model.CurrentMarker` which is already outside the `ViewModel`, and notify `ViewModel.wikiInfo(Model.CurrentMarker)` of the change so it automatically refresh the `View`, but I think I can only `subscribe()` to observables inside the `ViewModel`, and I don't know how to appply it:

```
var init = function() {
  ViewModel.wikiInfo.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    Model.currentMarker = newValue;
  }); // Not working
  ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
}
```

Another approach is to change the `Model.CurrentMarker`, and call `ViewModel.wikiInfo(Model.CurrentMarker)`.

I cannot do this because I don't have access to `ViewModel`.

```
var init = function() {
  Model.currentMarker = marker;
  ViewModel.wikiInfo(Model.CurrentMarker); // ViewModel is not created yet
  ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
}
```

### Notes:

Due to other code requirements:

- I can't create the `ViewModel` in the beginning of `init()`.
- I need to use `init()` outside the `ViewModel`, I can't put it inside my
  `ViewModel`.

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45565604/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-change-data-in-one-of-the-knockout-viewmodels-while-r/45568332#45568332

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work? Create a reference to the `ViewModel` instance.

```
var init = function() {
  Model.currentMarker = marker;
  var vm = new ViewModel();
  ko.applyBindings(vm);
  vm.wikiInfo(Model.CurrentMarker);
}
```

Comment: Strangely enough, I tried this method but it didn't work, now it did, so thanks!

Comment: @SamiAlmalki great! :)