# Find Observable DOM Element is Bound To

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I know this goes against knockout but I've gotten to a point where I'd like to create a control and bind an observable to it.  I'll know the field in which it will be bound to but not the model.  I'm wondering if there is a way to find which observable is bound to the text or value of an element?  I have a complex view model and the class that the observable could be bound to could be 3 layers deep.  I can get the context back by using:

```
ko.contextFor(this)
```

but that brings back the entire model, I'd like to just get back the observable.  Any suggestions?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45615949/3297291) I wrote earlier might be of help.

Answer (score 0):

I got it figured out!  For some reason the issue was because I was using a hidden field.  I changed the field to a text box and made it invisible and all started working.