# Add/remove class from div if minicart hasitem/noitem

Tags: php, magento, knockout.js, magento2

I want to add a class in parent div if minicart/cart is empty and remove same class if minicart/cart has an item(s). I made changes in minicart.phtml. Below is my code for that.

```
<div class="block block-minicart"
data-bind="css: { emptyBag: !!getCartParam('summary_count') == false }
                 data-role="dropdownDialog"
                 data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{
                    "appendTo":"[data-block=minicart]",
                    "triggerTarget":".showcart",
                    "timeout": "2000",
                    "closeOnMouseLeave": false,
                    "closeOnEscape": true,
                    "triggerClass":"active",
                    "parentClass":"active",
                    "buttons":[]}}'>
```

I have added `data-bind="css: { emptyBag: !!getCartParam('summary_count') == false }"` peace of code to check if cart is empty or not. but when I check console it's giving me an error of **getCartParam** is not defined.

I am new in Knockout.

Comment: The error means that there's no property named `getCartParam` in the current binding context. Here's [a tip to debug such an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45615949/3297291)

Comment: you have to make sure getCartParam is bound to `this` of the binding context. If thats unclear, please show your js code